# Pros & Cons of var datatype in .net 3.5

Tags: c#, keyword, var

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Use of var keyword in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41479/use-of-var-keyword-in-c)
>   [Use of “var” type in variable declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3658407/use-of-var-type-in-variable-declaration)

Hello everybody,

"Var keywork it require explicitly type casting Avoid boxing and unboxing value types where possible."

Is it advisable to use var keyword instead of explicit datatype?

Comment: `var` is not a datatype in .NET and the phrase you put inside the double quotes makes absolutely no sense.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [ReSharper Horizons blog](http://resharper.blogspot.com/2008/03/varification-using-implicitly-typed.html):

> 1. It induces better naming for local variables. When you read local variable declaration with explicit type, you have more information at
>      that moment and something like "IUnitTestElement current" makes sense.
>      However, when this local variable is used later, you read "current"
>      which takes some time to figure out the meaning. Using "var
>      currentElement" makes it easier to read at any place.
> 2. It induces better API. When you let compiler deduce type from method return type or property type, you have to have good types in
>      the first place. When you don't have explicit type in the
>      initialization expression, you have to have best names for members.
> 3. It induces variable initialization. It is generally a good practice to initialize variable in the declaration, and compiler needs
>      initializer to infer type for local variable declared with "var"
>      keyword.
> 4. It removes code noise. There are a lot of cases, when implicitly typed local will reduce amount of text developer needs to read, or
>      rather skip. Declaring local variable from new object expression or
>      cast expression requires specifying type twice, if we don't use "var".
>      With generics it can lead to a lot of otherwise redundant code.
>      Another example would be iteration variable in foreach over
>      Dictionary.
> 5. It doesn't require using directive. With var, you don't have explicit reference to type, as compiler infers type for you, so you
>      don't need to import namespace when you need a temporary variable.

The cons are potentially less readable code.  For instance the line
    `int myInt = 0;`
is still more straightforward for most than
    `var myInt = 0;`
but this is mainly due to the syntax we're all been looking at for years.

Answer (score 5):

`var` is not a data type, it is simply "syntactic sugar" for "let-the-compiler-infer-at-compile-time-what-actual-type-to-use".

So, you just need to understand the following type inferences:

```
var x = 4; //int
var y = 4.0; //double
var z = 4M; //decimal
var w = (string)null; //string
```