# Why prefer var strList = new List<string>(); over List<string> strList = new List<string>();?

Tags: c#, coding-style, var

Why when creating object it is preferred  to use **var** keyword than real type?

```
var strList  = new List<string>(); //good?
List<string> strList  = new List<string>(); //why bad?
```

Question is not just about `List<T>`.

Comment: There is no "good" or "bad". It's just a personal preference. The usage of the var keyword is just for convenience. The compiler will translate it into the actual type so there's no performance issue at runtime either.

Comment: Actually it's a matter of preference. The first annoys the heck out of me ESPECIALLY when its the return value of a function...

Comment: See also this SO question and the associated duplicates - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3967993/pros-cons-of-var-datatype-in-net-3-5/3968030#3968030

Comment: both will perform in equivalent manner according to me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use of var keyword in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41479/use-of-var-keyword-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not that `var` is good and the other one is bad. It's kind of personal preference.

If you want me to be more specific, I think you should use `var` only when the type is completely evident, such as:

```
var employee = new Employee();
```

On the other side it's probably a horrible idea to do:

```
var e = GetEmployees();
```

Because it's hard to tell whether if `e` is an `Employee` object, or a List, array, etc.

Also is probably right to use it when it saves you some effort while not diminishing readability:

```
ReallyLongClassName someidentifier = new ReallyLongClassName();
```

VS

```
var explanatoryIdentifier = new ReallyLongClassName();
```

But at last, it comes down to be personal preference, just **don't ever** save you some characters if you are damaging readability.

Answer (score 2):

The var keyword is great for **hiding noise**. When you have a statement like

```
List<string> strList  = new List<string>();
```

you can be certain that strList is of type List. Typing the type twice is a waste of your time. If you decide to change the type later, you have to change it in both places.

My preference is to always use var when specifying the type **is already obviously specified nearby**. I often use var for any instance variable when the type is not of significant importance.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a good practice use `List<string> strList  = new List<string>();` (explicit typing). It makes the code more *readable*, but they are equivalent.

Comment: I'd say "*readable*" in this case is a bit too subjective for one to truly be better than the other, but it does definitely make it more "*explicit*" as to the intent.

Comment: When you have `List<string>` it's more subjective is it better or worse, but when you have `Dictonary<int,Dictonary<string,List<int>>>` or something similar (like LINQu result) it's starting make sense. It's also easier, when your having a method, and you will change the return type (for example to interface) - you don't have to change it in many places in your code. In constructors - it only reduces the number of characters you need to type.

Comment: Sometimes I wonder if it would have been useful for them to allow syntax like `List<string> strList = new();` to keep the type on the left where it's most familiar to C# programmers.

Comment: @Downvoters care to comment?

Answer (score 1):

The argument for why var is good is that it removes the duplication of declaring the type.   Meaning if you want to modify the type that strList (which is a bad name) is, you do it in one spot.