# Difference between List values = new ArrayList(); is better then ArrayList values = new ArrayList();?

Tags: c#, .net

Run into term Anti-patterns in programming, and one of examples was this.

```
IList values = new ArrayList(); //Anti-pattern, bad
ArrayList values = new ArrayList(); //good
```

What is the difference between this two variants? Aren't they the same, same as with using [var keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15486589/why-preferred-var-strlist-new-liststring-then-liststring-strlist-new)?

Comment: Those are both terrible. It should be `var values = new List<MySpecificTypeNotObject>()`

Comment: Where did you get this from?

Comment: I'm not convinced that `List values = new ArrayList();` will compile in C#. Is this Java?

Comment: Was the example from an old Java version?  It's strange to see any sort of `List` without generics (`<T>`), and there's no type `List` in .Net (just `List<T>` and `ArrayList`).

Comment: It won't lol don't know up upvoted the incoreect example

Comment: if you want to use the `var Keyword` you need to do either of these 2 things `var values = new List<string>();` or var values = new ArrayList();` also make sure you reference `System.Collection`

Comment: `ArrayList` implements *no* generic types...

Comment: I would personally using `List<T>` because you can always to .ToArray() on the collection if needed ...

Comment: If this were legal C# (and it isn't), the first would not be an antipattern. Taking this question as *really* sourced from Java, it in fact seems to be turning the premise on its head. See this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/147468/why-should-the-interface-for-a-java-class-be-prefered

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume by `List` you really mean `IList`.

`IList values = new ArrayList();` just lets you view the `ArrayList` object as an `IList` object.  You could cast back to `ArrayList` if you wanted.

`ArrayList values = new ArrayList()` is the same as `var values = new ArrayList()`

Neither is really an anti-pattern.  If all you need is the methods that `IList` provides, it's considered good practice to only declare the type of object you need to use, regardless of what you assign it.  This is more important in the public interface of a type.  As a local variable; it doesn't really matter either way.

Comment: Does it compile? I thought List needs a type, e.g. List<int>

Comment: @MatthewWatson I assume he really means "IList".  `List<int>` won't compile either.

Answer (score 0):

In this isolation, it is mostly irrelevant.

```
List values = new ArrayList();
ArrayList values = new ArrayList();
var values = new ArrayList();
```

because here, values is declared inside a method body, and we do not care much about abstraction or isolation.

But I agree, that assigning to a List just puts a restriction to the use of *values* that has no advantage. One might say, this is an AnitPattern, but there are much more relevant AntiPatterns.

ArrayList and var are better, var will most often be most readable and maintainable. I personally would use var.

As an aside, hardly anyone uses these collections anymore, ArrayList is sometimes prefered to List, but I personally use the latter also here.

Answer (score 0):

The advantage with `IList` is there are many different classes that can be assigned to it.  This can be handy if you're sourcing data from different places that use different classes.

```
IList values;
values = new ArrayList();
values = new object[] {};
values = new List<int>();
values = new DataView();
```

However, if you use an `IList`, you can only use the methods defined by an `IList`.  If you define the variable as an `ArrayList` or any other concrete class, you have access to all of that class's methods.

```
ArrayList values = new ArrayList();
values.
```

Using the `var` keyword will tell the compiler to use the same class as the result of the expression.  It can be very useful if you have a very long-winded class.

```
var values = new ArrayList();
// values is ArrayList

// Assuming a function: List<int> GetIntegerList() { ... }
var values = GetIntegerList();
// values is List<int>

// Assuming a function: Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<Tuple<int, int, string>>>> GetSettingsCollection() { ... }
var values = GetSettingsCollection();
// values is Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<Tuple<int, int, string>>>>
```