# Different types evaluated for keyword var

Tags: c#, .net, types, var

I have following 2 blocks of code which aims to infer the type assigned to `var` keyword by the compiler.

```
var b = 0x80000000 - 0x1;
Console.WriteLine("b: {0}", b);
Console.WriteLine("b.GetType()={0}", b.GetType());

uint val1 = 0x80000000;
int val2 = 0x1;
var c = val1 - val2;
Console.WriteLine("c: {0}", c);
Console.WriteLine("c.GetType(): {0}", c.GetType());
```

---

**Output:**

```
  b: 2147483647                   //Result of UInt32-Int32
                                  //(as compiler assigns datatype in the
                                  //order of int, uint, long and ulong)
  b.GetType()=System.UInt32       //OK

  c: 2147483647                   //Uint32-Int32                               
  c.GetType(): System.Int64       //Not Understood, why not UInt32 ?
```

If `var b` and `var c` have almost same initialization- where `var c` is even explicit, then why does it give unexpected data-type System.Int64 ?

Comment: If you are subtracting a signed int from an unsigned int, then you have to entertain the possibility that the result will be signed. You also have to entertain the possibility that the result is larger than `Int32`. So what are you options? Hint: `Int64` will be the only type that can handle all possible values of `val1 - val2`.

Comment: @MattBurland: Yes Correct ! But why does compiler doesn't 'think' this during `var b`

Comment: As a note, var b can be evaluated during compilation, the equation won't even make it into the code. It's not doing the same as var c, which is acting on variables that do make it into the compiled code.

Comment: @NirajDoshi: because in the first case you are subtracting two *literals*. They are constant. The result can be calculated at compile time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because

`var b = 0x80000000 - 0x1;`

is already Computed. by Optimizations

But

```
var val1 = 0x80000000;
var val2 = 0x1;
var c = val1 - val2;
```

is Not computed yet. and compiler guess that the `val1` and `val2` may be changed later...

```
const uint val1 = 0x80000000;
const int val2 = 0x1;
var c = val1 - val2;
```

`c` is `UInt32` now because compiler compute it and knows the resault.

Because `val1` and `val2` are constant and Compiler knows that they will not get changed. so there is no need for `Int64` any more

Comment: If you are sure about it being computed during compilations, I have to accept it as an answer. Can you please provide a further reading link to it ? Thanks

Comment: see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14752559/does-c-sharp-compiler-calculate-math-on-constants) @NirajDoshi

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you do an operation between `int` and `uint`, `uint` is being transformed in a signed number.

Thus, in order to `uint` to be capable of store all its information (from 0 to  2<sup>3</sup> - 1) in a unsigned number, it must be casted to `long` (from -2<sup>63</sup> to 2<sup>63</sup> - 1), since the range of `int` is from -2<sup>31</sup> to 2<sup>31</sup> - 1.

Answer (score -1):

Compiler automatically expands type to 64 bits as this is the only integer that can hold result of operation between `UInt32` and `Int32`. Try changing to

```
ulong val1 = 0x80000000;
long val2 = 0x1;
```

and you will see a compilation error as compiler can't find a type to hold the result.

`Int64` is not the inferred type of `b` because compiler detects that constants fall into `Int32` range. Try

```
var b = 0x800000000000 - 0x1;
```

and you will see inferred type `long`

Comment: But then the same implies to the `var b` part of code.

Comment: After you edit of (0x80000000000) that's obvious because you are doing Int64-Int32